# How to set download path or location for a PhantomJSDriver in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to automate a scenario where in i have to download a file and need to read the file after it is downloaded. I am using the PhantomJSDriver from the Java Selenium API and I am just wondering is there a facility to download a file to a specific location on my machine by setting either capability, option or a profile to the PhantomJSDriver. Any help is greatly appreciated.